# ValueError unknown label type array sklearn- load_boston

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using the following code to check SGDClassifier

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

data = load_boston()
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data.data, data.target)

x_scalar = StandardScaler()
y_scalar = StandardScaler()

x_train = x_scalar.fit_transform(x_train)
y_train = y_scalar.fit_transform(y_train)
x_test = x_scalar.transform(x_test)
y_test = y_scalar.transform(y_test)

regressor = SGDClassifier(loss='squared_loss')
scores = cross_val_score(regressor, x_train, y_train, cv=5)
print  'cross validation r scores ', scores
print 'average score ', np.mean(scores)
regressor.fit_transform(x_train, y_train)
print 'test set r score ', regressor.score(x_test,y_test)
```

However when I run it I get deprecation warnings to reshape and 
the following value error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-4d64d112f5db> in <module>()
     18 
     19 regressor = SGDClassifier(loss='squared_loss')
---> 20 scores = cross_val_score(regressor, x_train, y_train, cv=5)

ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([ -1.89568750e+00,  -1.75715217e+00,  -1.68255622e+00,
        -1.66124309e+00,  -1.62927339e+00,  -1.54402088e+00,
        -1.49073806e+00,  -1.41614211e+00,  -1.40548554e+00,
        -1.34154616e+00,  -1.32023303e+00,  -1.30957647e+00,
        -1.27760677e+00,  -1.26695021e+00,  -1.25629365e+00,
        -1.20301082e+00,  -1.17104113e+00,  -1.16038457e+00,....]),)
```

What could be the probable error in the code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In classification tasks, the dependent variable (or the *target*) is categorical. We try to predict if a claim is fraudulent or not, for example. In regression, on the other hand, the dependent variable is numerical. It can be measured.

In the Boston Housing dataset, the dependent variable is *"Median value of owner-occupied homes in $1000's"* (You can see the description by executing `print(data.DESCR)`). It is a continuous variable and cannot be predicted with a classifier.

If you want to test the classifier, you can use another dataset. For example, change `load_boston()` to `load_iris()`. Note that you also need to remove the transformation for the target variable - it is for numerical variables. With these modifications, it should work correctly.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

data = load_iris()
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data.data, data.target)

x_scalar = StandardScaler()

x_train = x_scalar.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = x_scalar.transform(x_test)

classifier = SGDClassifier(loss='squared_loss')
scores = cross_val_score(classifier, x_train, y_train, cv=5)


scores
Out: array([ 0.33333333,  0.2173913 ,  0.31818182,  0.        ,  0.19047619])
```

Comment: the example usedhere uses boston dataset and executes without error [link](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=fZQeBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT97&dq=mastering+machine+learning+with+scikit+SGd&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwzpz916zOAhWMK48KHamrAQkQ6AEIMDAA#v=onepage&q=mastering%20machine%20learning%20with%20scikit%20SGd&f=false)

Comment: But it uses [SGDRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html), not [SGDClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html).